# Read, Write, Edit zip file metadata

Tags: zip, metadata

Is there a way to read, write and edit zip file metadata (comments, timestamps, etc.) that make the following possible:

1. - **Read and store zip file metadata**
   - **Unzip file**
   - **Zip unzipped files again**
   - **Write stored metadata** (comments, timestamps, etc. Obviously no checksums, length/size etc.)
   - => **Receive binary identical zip file**
2. - **Read and store zip file metadata**
   - **Unzip file**
   - **Change one file**
   - **Zip unzipped files again**
   - **Write stored metadata** (comments, timestamps, etc. Obviously no checksums, length/size etc.)
   - => **New zip file preserves file order, comments, unchanged files' timestamps**
3. - **Edit comment in zip file**
   - **Rest of zipfile remains untouched** (except what directly depends on the comment if appropriate)

Comment: Might be relevant: http://www.artpol-software.com/ZipArchive/KB/0610242300.aspx
http://www.info-zip.org/mans/zipinfo.html https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zip_(file_format)#File_headers

Comment: Also: https://github.com/zeeaero/stripzip/blob/609a5c75207ae4516e577d1595abf94b340ebcc7/src/stripzip_app.c#L104 https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/164071/can-we-preserve-the-timestamps-of-files-when-extracting-zip-archive https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5397957/pack-files-on-windows-and-preserve-folder-timestamps